# For loops and addition

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to use a for loop to fill the array with the numbers 1-8. Then add:

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + numb = x

And then save it to an variable called x. I've done filling the array, but I don't know how to calculate the summary of the array + the number you enter. Would appreciate some help a lot.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int array[8];
int numb;
int x; // x = summary of array + numb;

cin >> numb; // insert an number

for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
{
    array[i]=i+1;

}
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    cout << array[i] << " + ";
   }

}
```

Comment: Take note of `std::iota`. No need to reinvent it. You're also accessing `array[8]`, and look into `std::accumulate` to sum it.

Answer (score 3):

Change the last part to:

```
x = numb;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   x = x + array[i];
}

cout<<x<<endl;
```

---

Realistically though, if you wanted to add the first n whole numbers, there's a formula:

```
(n*(n+1))/2;
```

so your whole program would be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n = 8;
int numb;
cin >> numb; // insert an number

int x = n*(n+1)/2+numb;
cout<<x<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the initial loop, remove the =:

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) { array[i]=i+1; }
```

For adding all the elements of an array, then adding numb:

```
var x=0;
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) { x += array[i]; }
x+=numb;
```

Then you can cout you x variable.

Comment: +1 but for future reference you should consider explaining *why* he should change the `<=` to `<`. It doesn't help him if you just tell him what to fix. The important thing is for him to **understand** what needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're required to use `for` loops and arrays (e.g., this is homework), you might want to consider code more like:

```
std::vector<int> array(8);

// fill array:
std::iota(begin(array), end(array), 1);

int numb;    
std::cin >> numb;

int total = std::accumulate(begin(array), end(array), numb);

std::cout << "Result: " << total;
```